# How to create loop with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes: `df` and `df1`, where I have information about chromosome and coordinates, for example.

```
df <- data.frame(
  chr = c(2,3,4,1,6,7,3),
  coord = c(112,333,444,111,332,221,113)
)

df1 <- data.frame(
  chr = c(2,2,5,7,9,3,11),
  coord = c(110,331,439,117,338,220,157)
)
```

I want to create a loop, where, firstly, I need to find a macth between values from column `chr`(chromosome), where chr == chr. After that I need select values from `chr`, where coords will equal +- 10 and calculate distance (create column for it).

For example: in `df` chromosome 2 will match with chomosome 2 from `df1`, after that it is needed to compare values from `coord`: 112 and 110 are fit to condition(equal +-10). And the output looks like:

```
chr    coord1     distance
2       110          2
```

This is my code, but I can not fix it:

```
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  if (df$chr[i] == df1$chr) {
    i1 <- which(outer(df$coord, df1$coord, FUN = function(x, y) abs(x - y) <=10), arr.ind = TRUE)
    transform(data.frame(a = df$coord[i1[,1]], b = df1$coord[i1[,2]]), distance = abs(as.numeric(a) - as.numeric(b)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a join on `df` and `df1`, create a `distance` column by subtracting the `coord` values and keep only the rows where `distance` is less than equal to 10.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df, df1, by = 'chr') %>%
  mutate(distance = abs(coord.x - coord.y)) %>%
  filter(distance <= 10)

#  chr coord.x coord.y distance
#1   2     112     110        2
```

Similarly, in base R -

```
merge(df, df1, by = 'chr') |>
  transform(distance = abs(coord.x - coord.y)) |>
  subset(distance <= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` as

```
out <- merge(df, df1, by = 'chr')
out$distance <- with(out, abs(coord.x - coord.y))
out[out$distance <= 10,]
```